# Would courts sentence differently if we used a different numeral system?

Tags: social-psychology

I hear a lot in the media about people sentenced to go to jail for a number of years divisible by 10.

Does our numeral system affect it? Would courts sentence the same if we counted - for example - in base 7 (when "10 years" means 7 years, "20 years" means 14 years and so on)?
Which other important issues can be affected by this?